# ODE for electric charge $x$ in a circuit with an inductor, resistor and capacitor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The electric charge $x$ in a circuit with an inductor, resistor and capacitor is given by the equation:
$$Lx''(t)+ Rx'(t)+x/C = E \cos(pt)$$
where $L, R, C, p, E$ are constants and $t$ is time. Prove that if $R$ is positive, the exponential terms in the solution tend to zero as $t$ tends to infinity and find the solution assuming that these terms can be ignored. With this assumption, show that for a given values of $E, P, R$ the largest value of $x$ occurs when $\sqrt{LC} = 1/p$

My try is as follows:

$x=\frac{E}{1+L^{2}\,C^{2}\,P^{4}-2\,L\,C\,P^{2}+P^{2}\,R^{2}\,C^{3}}\,*\left(\left(C-L\,C^{2}\,P^{2}\right)\,\cos\left(P\,t\right)+P\,R\,C^{2}\,\sin\left(P\,t\right)\right)=0$

$x'=\frac{E}{1+L^{2}\,C^{2}\,P^{4}-2\,L\,C\,P^{2}+P^{2}\,R^{2}\,C^{3}}\,*\left(\left(L\,C^{2}\,P^{3}-CP\right)\,\sin\left(P\,t\right)+P^{2}\,R\,C^{2}\,\cos\left(P\,t\right)\right)=0$

I can't proceed further. How should I continue after this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [RLC wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit), where your questions are answered.

Concerning the exponential terms tending to zero, see the subsection "transient response". It seems to me that, in order for the solutions $s_1$ and $s_2$ of the characteristic equation to be real and negative, not only $R$, but also $L$ should be positive.

For the second part of the question, regarding x being maximal when $\sqrt{LC}=1/p$, see the subsection "sinusoidal steady state"

Also have a look at the [wikipedia page on harmonic oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators), which is mathematically identical to your problem. In particular, check out the subsection "sinusoidal driving" of the section"driven harmonic oscillators".